# Even Axis in R Charts

Tags: r, charts, shiny

I've searched a bit, but I'm not able to find a way to acheive my axis goals.  There are really 2 questions here.

1. How can I guarantee the spacing between my major ticks is the same?  If it means some dots overlap, then so be it.
2. Is there a way to add a zoom/date range control to this chart?  Data goes from 2013 to current and is continually added.

2.b.  If I do this, is there a way to have it as you zoom out it automatically start bucketing by week, then month, then year? and of course the inverse.

Here is where you can get the data: https://opendata.miamidade.gov/311/311-Service-Requests-Miami-Dade-County/dj6j-qg5t

Here is the image of the current chart: 
[image]

Note that I am doing this to learn R, and hence any erraneous suggestions are also appreciated.  Here is the code that generates this:

```
#Graphics Visualizations Package
library("ggvis") 
#Adds %>% forward pipe operator
library("magrittr") 
#adds grouping and manipulations
library("dplyr")
#adds data fiendlyness stuffs
library("tidyr")
library("shiny")
library("checkpoint")

checkpoint("2016-03-29")

rData <- read.csv("C:\\data\\Miami_311.csv", 
                 header=TRUE, 
                 sep=",")
rDSamp <- rData[sample(1:length(rData$Case.Owner), 1000),]

#Convert to known date time
rDSamp$Ticket.Created.Date...Time <- 
  rDSamp$Ticket.Created.Date...Time %>%
  as.POSIXct(format="%m/%d/%Y") %>%
  as.character()

FilterDateRange = function(data, feature, minDate, maxDate) {
  minDate = minDate %>% 
          as.POSIXct(format="%m/%d/%Y") %>% 
          as.character() 
  maxDate = maxDate %>% 
          as.POSIXct(format="%m/%d/%Y") %>% 
          as.character() 
  result = subset(data, data[feature] <= maxDate)
  subset(result, result[feature] >= minDate)
}

d <- rDSamp %>% 
  FilterDateRange("Ticket.Created.Date...Time", "1/1/2013", "12/31/2013")    %>%
  group_by(Ticket.Created.Date...Time, Case.Owner) %>%
  summarise(
    count = n()
  ) %>%
  arrange(Ticket.Created.Date...Time) 

xAxisValues = "1/1/2013" %>%
            as.Date(format="%m/%d/%Y") %>%
            as.character() %>%
            as.Date() %>%
            seq(by = "1 months", length.out = 12)

d %>%
  ggvis(~Ticket.Created.Date...Time, ~count) %>%
  layer_points(fill = ~Case.Owner) %>%
  add_tooltip(function(data){ 
    paste("Owner:", data$Case.Owner, "<br>","Date:",     data$Ticket.Created.Date...Time)
    }, "hover") %>%
  add_axis("x", 
       title = "Date",
       values = xAxisValues, 
       ticks = 365,
       properties = axis_props(
       majorTicks = list(strokeWidth = 2)))
```